# Android Material Spinner Typeface

Tags: android, spinner, typeface

I'm using MaterialSpinner from https://github.com/ganfra/MaterialSpinner

I'm not able to change Typeface. It seems that ms_typeface property changes the floating label but no the text of the spinner.

Any hints?

This is my current xml:

```
<fr.ganfra.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
android:id="@+id/settings_gender"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/settings_email_til"
android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
app:ms_multiline="false"
app:ms_hint="@string/settings_personal_info_gender"
app:ms_enableFloatingLabel="true"
app:ms_enableErrorLabel="false"
app:ms_floatingLabelText="@string/settings_personal_info_gender"
app:ms_baseColor="@color/primary_text"
app:ms_highlightColor="@null"
app:ms_errorColor="@null"
app:ms_typeface="OpenSans-Light.ttf"
app:ms_thickness="0dp"
app:ms_hintColor="@color/greyish"
app:ms_arrowColor="@color/greyish"
app:ms_arrowSize="16dp"
app:ms_alignLabels="true"
app:ms_floatingLabelColor="@color/greyish"/>
```

Comment: In which folder of the project is "OpenSans-Light.ttf"?

Comment: in 'assets' folder

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items) {

     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
             View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
             Typeface externalFont=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/your-custom-font.ttf");
             ((TextView) v).setTypeface(externalFont);
             return v;
     }


     public View getDropDownView(int position,  View convertView,  ViewGroup parent) {
              View v =super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
             Typeface externalFont=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/your-custom-font.ttf");
             ((TextView) v).setTypeface(externalFont);
             return v;
     }
```